# You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I'm trying to compile my Vue.js app with `webpack` but I get this warning in the browser.

> You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

What does this mean? How do I resolve the error?

Answer (score 56):

This error pops up if you try to use non-precompiled Vue templates.

To fix this, set the [`runtimeCompiler` option in `vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#runtimecompiler) to `true`:

```
module.exports = {
  runtimeCompiler: true
}
```

Note that this will include additional JavaScript payload into your distribution.

Alternatively, you can use precompiled Vue templates.

Answer (score 48):

This is because the version of `vue` without the template compiler (needed) is included by default. To override this default, add this to your `webpack.config.js`:

```
// webpack.config.js
{
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
        },
    },
}
```

Source: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/215

Answer (score 30):

I still had an error after setting the runtimeCompiler to true in `vue.config.js` file.

You can simply edit your src/main.js file

from : `import Vue from 'vue'`

to   :  `import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';`

Answer (score 15):

If you compile your app with vue-cli-service add the following code to `vue.config.js` depending upon compiler:

```
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
      }
    }
  }
```

If you compile your app with webpack add the following code to `webpack.config.js`:

```
    resolve: {
      alias: {
         vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

Use **render** function

```
new Vue({
    el: 'body',
     render: function(createElement) {
        return createElement(hello)
    } });
```

Comment: Yes! This allows for the use of the runtime-only build, which is significantly smaller.

Comment: what is hello and how can I have 2 different url paths render 2 different components?

Comment: Is there any tooling for creating `render` functions from templates without digging into builds?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a typo (lowercase).  I had:

```
import Vue from "Vue";
```

instead of

```
import Vue from "vue";
```